# Angular $routeProvider param conflict

Tags: angularjs, routes, route-provider

I have a problem with routing in my app.

```
    // ============ SITE CATEGORY ============
$routeProvider.when( '/:slug/' , {
    controller: 'siteCategory',
    templateUrl : 'partials/site/category.html'
});

// ============ LOGIN & REGISTER ============
$routeProvider.when( '/login' , {
    controller: 'login',
    templateUrl : 'partials/site/login.html'
});

$routeProvider.when( '/register' , {
    controller: 'register',
    templateUrl : 'partials/site/register.html'
});
```

I want that url (http://localhost/app/books) load category template and it works but when i go to /login or /register it also loads category template instead of given.

Comment: remove $routeProvider before when

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mxR2me9b
u mean like that? tried that but still the same result

Answer (score 2):

Try to change sequence `:slug` should be at the end.

```
$routeProvider.when( '/register' , {
    controller: 'register',
    templateUrl : 'partials/site/register.html'
})
.when( '/login' , {
    controller: 'login',
    templateUrl : 'partials/site/login.html'
})
.when( '/:slug/' , {
    controller: 'siteCategory',
    templateUrl : 'partials/site/category.html'
});
```

Comment: Great! Works. One more thing i have 
 .otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/404'
 });

How to make it http://localhost/blabla
Takes me to 404 instead to :slug ?

Comment: localhost/blabla will send you to localhost/:slug because there are equal. Change /:slug/ into ex: /book/:slug and call it localhost/book/something

Comment: Oh yea but i really want that nice url without /book/ is that possible? I got categories ex. books, movies i want urls to be:
http://localhost/books, http://localhost/movies
That looks much nicer but it applies my :slug :(

Comment: @DamianWójcik validate the slug in `resolve` and redirect if it doesn't validate

Comment: @charlietfl how should it look like?

Comment: @DamianWójcik something like:  http://plnkr.co/edit/hGYd7QGsdWg7J5UG3cPF?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl great, thanks. I got one more thing. I need to get valid slugs from an $http.get. I modified your code but it doesn't work. Please take a look:
https://pastebin.com/aCc4wRGb

Comment: @DamianWójcik `$http` is asynchronous but it also returns a promse. Use that promise instead of the `$q` ones. Also `indexOf()` only works on array not object

Comment: @charlietfl still cant figure that out :( please help: https://pastebin.com/0vbecVMb